# THREE .JS raycasting performance

Tags: javascript, three.js, raycasting

I am trying to find the closest distance from a point to large, complex Mesh along a plane in a direction range:

```
 for (var zDown in verticalDistances) {
    var myIntersect = {};  
   for (var theta = Math.PI / 2 - 0.5; theta < Math.PI / 2 + 0.5; theta += 0.3) {
                var rayDirection = new THREE.Vector3(
                    Math.cos(theta),
                    Math.sin(theta),
                    0
                ).transformDirection(object.matrixWorld);
                 //  console.log(rayDirection);

                _raycaster.set(verticalDistances[zDown].minFacePoint, rayDirection, 0, 50);
                //  console.time('raycast: ');
                var intersect = _raycaster.intersectObject(planeBufferMesh);
                //   console.timeEnd('raycast: '); // this is huge!!! ~ 2,300 ms

                //   console.log(_raycaster);
                //    console.log(intersect);
                if (intersect.length == 0) continue;
                if ((!('distance' in myIntersect)) || myIntersect.distance > intersect[0].distance) {
                    myIntersect.distance = intersect[0].distance;
                    myIntersect.point = intersect[0].point.clone();
                }
            }
// do stuff
}
```

I get great results with mouse hover on the same surface but when performing this loop the raycasting is taking over 2 seconds per cast. The only thing i can think of is that the BackSide of the DoubleSide Material is a ton slower?

Also i notice as I space out my verticalDistances[zDown].minFacePoint to be farther apart raycast starts to speed up up (500ms /cast). So as the distance between verticalDistances[i].minFacePoint and verticalDistances[i+1].minFacePoint increases, the raycaster performs faster.

I would go the route of using octree but the mouse hover event works extremely well on the exact same planeBuffer. Is this a side of Material issue,. that could be solved by loading 2 FrontSide meshes pointing in opposite directions?

Thank You!!!!

EDIT: it is not a front back issue.  I ran my raycast down the front and back side of the plane buffer geometry with the same spot result.  Live example coming.

EDIT 2: working example [here](http://command.carlsonsw.com/samples/).  Performance is little better than Original case but still too slow.  I need to move the cylinder in real time.  I can optimize a bit by finding certain things, but mouse hover is instant. When you look at the console time the first two(500ms) are the results i am getting for all results.

EDIT 3:  added a mouse hover event, that performs the same as the other raycasters.  I am not getting results in my working code that i get in this sample though.  The results I get for all raycast are the same as i get for the first 1 or 2 in the sample around 500ms.  If i could get it down to 200ms i can target the items i am looking for and do way less raycasting.  I am completely open to suggestions on better methods.  Is octree the way to go?

```
raycast: : 467.27001953125ms
raycast: : 443.830810546875ms
```

EDIT 4:  @pailhead Here is my plan. 
1. find closest grid vertex to point on the plane.  I can do a scan of vertex in x/y direction then calculate the min distance.
2. once i have that closest vertex i know that my closest point has to be on a face containing that vertex. So i will find all faces with that vertex using the object.mesh.index.array and calculate the plane to point of each face.  Seems like a ray cast should be a little bit smarter than a full scan when intersecting a mesh and at least cull points based on max distance? @WestLangley any suggestions?

EDIT 5:
@pailhead thank you for the help.  Its appreciated.  I have really simplified my [example](http://command.carlsonsw.com/samples/)(<200 lines with tons more comments);  Is raycaster checking every face?  Much quicker to pick out the faces within the set raycasting range specified in the constructor and do a face to point calc.  There is no way this should be looping over every face to raycast. I'm going to write my own PlaneBufferGeometry raycast function tonight, after taking a peak at the source code and checking octree.  I would think if we have a range in the raycaster constructor, pull out plane buffer vertices within that range ignoring z.  Then just raycast those or do a point to plane calculation.  I guess i could just create a "mini" surface from that bounding circle and then raycast against it. But the fact that the max distance(manual uses "far") doesn't effect the speed of the raycaster makes me wonder how much it is optimized for planeBuffer geometries. FYI your 300k loop is ~3ms on jsfiddle.

EDIT 6:  Looks like all meshes are treated the same in the raycast function.  That means it wont smart hunt out the area for a plane Buffer Geometry.  Looking at [mesh.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/5e78337be14a2058f2aa998de2433d43df746627/src/objects/Mesh.js) lines 266 we loop over the entire index array.  I guess for a regular mesh you dont know what faces are where because its a TIN, but a planeBuffer could really use a bounding box/sphere rule, because your x/y are known order positions and only the Z are unknown. Last edit, Answer will be next

Comment: Why do you think the backside or front side should matter? Can you post some live code?

Comment: Working on example now.  Front/back side do not make difference.   Is there a difference between setting the raycast from camera and mouse then from point direction?  I  normalized my Ray direction thinking maybe some weird floating point issue.  Thanks.  Will be back with example in couple hours

Comment: @pailhead [link](http://command.carlsonsw.com/samples/)

Comment: FWIW, when the raycaster tries to intersect a backside, it simply re-orders the vertices of the face, which is a trivial operation.

Comment: you're performing dozens of raycasts against an object with 300k faces. that's why it's slow.

Comment: You can try to use [`THREE.Plane()`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/math/Plane) and its `.distanceToPoint ( point )` method.

Comment: @AndyRay my mouse hover event is pretty fast.  I will add a mouse hover to highlight face and I think we will see sub 10ms results.

Comment: @prisoner849 will this work on a non-flat plane?  Will definitely test.  I think the issue is that the plane has elevations added every node so a simple vector normal to the plane cast from the point wont work?

Comment: @AndyRaym If i set the max distance it doesnt seem to help the raycasting performance.  Does it still check against all faces or is it smart enough to filter?

Comment: I'm not sure if i understand the code completely, or what's even supposed to happen. Could it have something to do with the size of the mesh and the number of operations you are trying to do? Before going down the fancy route of octrees, i'd simply break down this grid into smaller segments compute bounding boxes, cull early based on that....

Comment: `console.time('foo'); for(var i = 0 ; i < 300000; i++){}console.timeEnd('foo')` alone may be well above 10ms. Your code is way too complicated to be profiled here, you should read about [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This isn't really related to three's raycasting.

Comment: I'll try to minimize the cpde but the issue is it is slow when there is alot of data, and I need optimization techniques. I'm adding detailed notes to the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest issue resolved is filtering out faces of planeBufferGeometry based on vertex index.  With a planeBufferGeometry you can find a bounding sphere or rectangle that will give you the faces you need to check.  they are ordered in x/y in the index array so that filters out many of the faces.  I did an indexOf the bottom left position and lastIndexOf the top right corner position in the index array.  RAYCASTING CHECKS EVERY FACE

I also gave up on finding the distance from each face of the object and instead used vertical path down the center of the object.  This decreased the ray castings needed.

Lastly I did my own face walk through and used the traingle.closestPointToPoint() function on each face.

Ended up getting around 10ms per point to surface calculation(single raycast) and around 100 ms per object (10 vertical slices) to surface.  I was seeing 2.5 seconds per raycast and 25+ seconds per object prior to optimization.

Answer (score 1):

FYI: for max speed, you could use math. There is no need to use ray casting. https://brilliant.org/wiki/3d-coordinate-geometry-equation-of-a-plane/

Comment: this is not a flat plane.  It is a plane that has elevations added for every "node" .  I was thinking i could find the closest node then start looping over faces connected to that node using a method you suggested, but it would add alot of complexity to the code, when hopefully I have a simple ray cast error

Comment: Why does it even matter that it's a plane? I think your question needs editing. You have a "mesh" (or "geometry" in three.js land), the fact that it originates from a plane is totally irrelevant. It would be much more appropriate to say **"im raycasting against an extremely complex mesh, with hundreds of thousands of triangles** (12 times).

Answer (score 0):

I started out making planes for terrains and extruding with height maps its easier just to download blender for free and follow a heightmap terrain blender tutorial it take 10 minutes turn it into a gtfl or whatever I might have spelt that wrong
and then you do this its only one iterations
this is the code to speed up its only one iteration

```
if( typeof mesh[1] == 'object' ){
var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster(fued.position, new THREE.Vector3(0, -1, 0));
var intersections = raycaster.intersectObject( mesh[1] );
if (intersections.length > 0 ){
fued.position.y = fued.position.y - intersections[0].distance + 2500;
}}
```